# rescued_data column of schemaEvolutionMode is not showing in output of readStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to databricks (pyspark), I have few queries regarding pyspark syntax:

1. Do we need to follow any specific order when using options in `readStream` and `writeStream`? For example:

   ```
   (dataframe.readStream
       .format("cloudFile)
       .option("cloudFiles.format": "avro")
       .option("multiline", True)
       .schema(schema)
       .load(path))
   ```
2. Delta table creation with both `tableName` and `location` options, is that right? If I use both only I can see the files like `.parquet`, `_delta` log, checkpoint in the specified path and if I use `tableName` only I can see the table in hive meta store/spark `catalog.bronze` of SQL editor in databricks.

The syntax I use, is it OK to use both `.tableName()` and `.location()` option?

```
(DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) 
      .tableName("%s.%s_%s" % (layer, domain, deltaTable)) 
      .addColumn("x", "INTEGER")
      .location(path)
      .execute())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we need to follow any specific order when using options in `readStream` and `writeStream`?

No order required you can use different options like format, option, schema, etc in any order

> Delta table creation with both `tableName` and `location` options, is that right? If I use both only I can see the files like `.parquet`, `_delta` log, checkpoint in the specified path and if I use `tableName` only I can see the table in hive meta store/spark `catalog.bronze` of SQL editor in databricks.

If you specify the location explicitly, it is external table (this table  is created under specified location and once table alone is deleted the data still persists under data store location like mounted ADLS) and if you don't specify location it is managed table (create under default location and this table can be deleted once the table is deleted)

---

And to the question in the heading/top of  the question about rescued data column:

> rescued_data column of schemaEvolutionMode is not showing in output of readStream

Even though we use option to see rescued data, we need to select that rescued data column so that we can see it in the resultant dataframe. If we don't select it in: `df.select()`, then we can't see it in the result.